# Selecting/Invoking Menubuttons in python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a menu that calls an SQL database for life expectancy data across the world. I'm having trouble with menubutton, as I want to set the first value ("No region selected") as my initial value. There are three things that I want: how to set the value as the default (ideally the equivalent of invoked for normal radiobuttons), is there a better for what I want option than menubutton, and is there a decent web page that can help me (tutorialspoint got me in the initial direction, but unless I'm looking in the wrong places, I can't find how to select and invoke radiobuttons in the menubutton).

Ideally, I'd also like advise on how not to have the menuoptions stretch up everywhere too. A limit of say 20?

Here's a look of a somewhat stripped down piece of my code.

Edit: I've found a solution to my select/invoke issues. mb.menu.invoke(0)

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter
import sqlite3


def selectStuff():
    selectionRegion = str(countryVar.get())
    mb.config(text = selectionRegion)



sqlLocation = 'AllData/LifeExpectency.sqlite'
sqlDB = sqlite3.connect(sqlLocation)

cursor = sqlDB.cursor()

root = Tk()
frameCountry = Frame(root)
frameCountry.pack()
stringCountry= StringVar()        
labelCountry = Label(frameCountry, textvariable=stringCountry)
stringCountry.set("Select Region")
labelCountry.pack()
'''-------------------------------'''
mb =  Menubutton ( frameCountry, relief=RAISED, activebackground="white")
mb.grid()
mb.menu  =  Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0 )
mb["menu"]  =  mb.menu
sql1 = "SELECT Country FROM total_lifespan"

countryVar = StringVar()

mb.menu.add_radiobutton  ( label="No Region Selected", variable =countryVar, 
                          value = "No Region Selected", command =selectStuff)

try:
    cursor.execute(sql1)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        mb.menu.add_radiobutton  ( label=row, variable =countryVar, value = row, 
                                  command =selectStuff)
except:
    print "Error: unable to retrieve data." 

mb.pack()
'''-------------------------------'''
#Edit:

mb.menu.invoke(0)
#/Edit:
root.mainloop()

sqlDB.close()
```

Comment: You can use a sub-menu instead of a radio button if you want someone to select one region.  You can limit the menu options to 20 programmatically by keeping track of how many have been created.  You could also use a separate scrolled widget, a listbox for example, that would pop-up.

Comment: Okay, how would one do that?